# Make a car look smooth not flat

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

This is my first attempt on a car, the Nissan GTR. But as everyone knows a car does not have flat faces. When I try to use Smooth Vertex, my car gets messed up. How can I make my car look smooth and not flat-faced? This is what it looks like now:

[image: Nissan GTR]

[image]

Comment: Try "Smooth" in "Object Mode" not "Smooth Vertex". You may also want to add a "Subsurf" modifier.

Comment: Dontwalk this worked really well, the only thing is, the back of a nissan GTR, the 'trunk' is going in a sharp angle from the bottom to the left, now it is smooth, how do u get that ONE part not to be smooth? haha

Comment: In "Edit Mode" Try selecting the edge and then increasing the "Mean Crease" in the transform panel (Toggled on/off with the "N" key). Or you could add a loop cut(s) close to the edge you'd like crisper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the faces in Edit Mode, then select the menu option: Mesh/Faces/Shade smooth

Comment: this worked also, the only thing is, the back of a nissan GTR, the 'trunk' is going in a sharp angle from the bottom to the left, now it is smooth, how do u get that ONE part not to be smooth? haha

Comment: @LucStey Only select the faces you want to be smooth, then do as Reden said.

Comment: @Lukaash this is the result, http://prntscr.com/b0oc7l is there a way to blend them in together? :P

Comment: @LucStey Upload your model using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and i'll have a look.

Comment: @LucStey After looking at it with a SubSurf and a little tweaking, it looks fine to me. What exactly is the problem with the SubSurf?

Comment: @Lukaash Like how it is with Subsurf, everything is smooth, thats fine but the back of the car has to be a sharp edge like; http://prntscr.com/b0oldt < that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39355/discussion-between-luka-ash-and-luc-stey).

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways you can do it.

**1. Subdivision surface modifier**

You can use a subdivision surface modifier to make the faces smooth. But, the problem with that is the car is too rounded.

[image]

**2. Smooth shading**

You also can use smooth shading, located within the toolbar on the left. But, you must make sure that all the faces are quads.

**3. Bevel**

You can use bevel at the sharp edges. In edit mode, select the edges you want to make it smooth and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use subsurf modifier and then add a loop cut to make the edge sharp.

[image]

You also need to use smooth shading.

[image]

P.S sorry about my english.im malaysian