# Polygons are rendered as smooth colors instead of solid

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render low polygon version of a model that I downloaded. Show in the image are two models, on the left is a low polygon model that I drew myself, the other is a high polygon model that I've used decimate modifier on the torso

[image]

I'm trying to achieve a "low polygon" look (like the model on the left), but when I view the model on the right those polygons appear not as solid colours, instead some smoothing looks like is happening. Is there a property that is controlling this somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a car look smooth not flat](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52036/make-a-car-look-smooth-not-flat)

Comment: @leander I think he means the opposite of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Tools panels `T` under Shading you can toggle between Flat and Smooth.
It can be applied to the whole object or only to some selected faces when in edit mode (the option then moves to the Shading/UVs tab).

---

*Update*: This option as now moved to the top-left corner of the 3d viewport, under `Object` in object mode and `Face` in edit mode.